# Hamburger menu disappeared

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu

Have looked on SO for an answer, but I seem to have one stemming from mods I did to style.css header. Actually, not sure mods have 'pushed' hamburger menu off the screen or I just need to adjust colour. When one forst goes to site - menu items appear in word format, not collapsed menu, then disappear.
I am working on WP, using Genesis framework for my website - shinwag.com

```css
.responsive-menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive-menu-icon::before {
    content: "\f333";
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal 20px/1 'dashicons';
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.site-header .responsive-menu-icon::before {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.shinwag.com/wp-content/themes/lifestyle-pro/style.css             line 1959
.genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu > .menu-item > .sub-menu, .genesis-nav-menu.responsive-menu   in this class put display:block; remove display:none;

Comment: Thank you. Did that, still not displaying.

Comment: Sorry, update - now menu items are appearing in word format - no sign of hamburger menu.

Comment: your hamburger icon is there but not displayed because of icon content..so check there......

Comment: I'm not a big techie - could you elaborate on what to check? What should I change?

Comment: Thanks for your input